# Including Bootstrap 4 script (Jquery, Popper, and BS4) in php footer wont allow header dropdown nav to work?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my code dry and running into a problem where my nav bar in my header won't work properly on the dropdown option.

I have tried to include the script in the header and footer which both have not worked. The only solution that I have successfully got to work was by including my script tags inside of the body.

```php
<?php 
    include "header.php";

    if ($_GET['page'] == ""){
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=/?page=home' />";
    }else{
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        include $page.".php";
    }

    include "footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include CSS in the `<head></head` tag and the JavaScript code before `</body>` tag close.